# how to start always at the last used activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I've an application with a lot of activities. When returning from desktop or lockscreen, the expected behaviour is, that the last used activity is shown again.

This works flawlessly if the application is started again from the normal desktop icon. But if I add it to the lockscreen "widgetlocker" and start it from there, there is always the main activity shown. And unfortunately, if I close the main activity later by returning via back button, I return to all other instances of this main activity.

It might be related to the fact that I'm returned to the lockscreen when closing the application directly after having opened it from the lockscreen.

But I'm quite puzzled why the behaviour is different if I open from lockscreen or open normally.

Any suggestions? How can I force the application to be ALWAYS return to the last used screen?

```
    ...
    # main activity:
    <activity android:name="StudyOptions"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|locale">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="com.ankidroid.category.DECK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.anki" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="DeckPicker" 
        android:label="DeckPicker"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|locale"/>
   ...
```

Comment: `I've an application with a lot of activities` This is a hint that maybe something is wrong with your design

Answer (score 0):

how about maintaining the activity changes like a state machine. Giving a state number for each activity and persist the current in the database. And recover the last state from the database on startup and display the corresponding activity.